# pipe to sudo -E bash -

Tags: sudo, nodejs, curl

I was wondering what is the purpose of piping the downloaded file by `curl` into `sudo -E bash -` in the following shell:

`curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_5.x | sudo -E bash -`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's a short way of executing a script without having to save the file and then execute it. When you save the file and then execute it, a number of things can go wrong:

- User didn't type the filename correctly
- User didn't use the correct shell (maybe ran `sh foo.sh` instead of `bash foo.sh`)
- User tried to execute the file instead of setting bash on it (`./foo.sh`), and forgot to set execute permissions
- User forgot to use `sudo`

By providing a single command line to execute, the developers can decrease the number of places where things can go wrong due to luser error.

Personally, I despise piping curl to bash. [It's not safe.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34016579/2072269)

Answer (score 9):

This command would download file and attempt to execute it with root privileges.

Comment: Thank you, but what is the pupose of `-E` option and `-` at the end of command ?

Comment: @Youssef `-E` preserves environment variables (say variables for proxy settings) and `-` tells bash to read commands from standard input, i.e., the pipe.

Answer (score 2):

Agreed with @muru you should not execute some random bash script from the internet.

Better option to install NPM & Node.js is to download the binary from [Download | Node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/) and follow the [official instructions](https://github.com/nodejs/help/wiki/Installation) from the Node.js project.

1. Unzip the binary archive to any directory you wanna install Node, I use `/usr/local/lib/nodejs`.

   ```
   sudo mkdir -p /usr/local/lib/nodejs
   # instead of XX use the version number you downloaded
   sudo tar -xJvf node-XX-XX.tar.xz -C /usr/local/lib/nodejs
   ```
2. Open `~/.profile`, add below to the end

   ```
   # Nodejs
   VERSION=vXX.XX.0 # <--- Put the version you downloaded
   DISTRO=linux-x64
   export PATH=/usr/local/lib/nodejs/node-$VERSION-$DISTRO/bin:$PATH
   ```
3. Refresh profile

   ```
   . ~/.profile
   ```
4. Check if it works

   ```
   node -v
   npm version
   ```